# Proper way to update big table from in given intervals

Tags: postgresql

I have table `Recommendations` which contains 100 recommendations for each user, and there are 50k+ users so table contains ~5000000 rows. Each row consist of 2 columns: `UserId` (FK), `ContentId` (fk). Recommendations come from Oryx which is located on separate server. What I need is to update recommendations every 24h with as little impact on (database) performance as possible. What will be the best way of doing it? Creating temp table, filling it with data and then swap tables? Or something else?

(Updating recommendations means replacing 5000000 rows with completely new 5000000 rows)

Comment: Does it really have to be done in one fell swoop?  Why not have it replace them one UserId worth of data at a time as Oryx computes them?

Comment: Do you know how I can 'hook' to oryx so I can update db when it computes new recommendations for user?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a temp table. Just do it inside a transaction

```
create table t (
    id integer primary key
);

insert into t 
select generate_series(1, 10);

begin;
delete from t;
insert into t 
select generate_series(11, 20);
commit;
```